# Enumerating pairs of elements in a Set (Swift 3)

Tags: iterator, set, swift3

The Swift 3 `IteratorProtocol` documentation says : "Copying an iterator is safe, but advancing one copy of an iterator by calling its `next()` method may invalidate other copies of that iterator."

So, this might not work:

```
    var i = set.makeIterator()
    while let obji = i.next() {
        var j = i
        while let objj = j.next() { // Possible error : might invalidate i
            ...some code...
        }
    }
```

So, I wrote this:

```
var objects = [Object](set)
for i in 0..<objects.count {
    for j in (i+1)..<objects.count {
        ...some code...
    }
}
```

But isn't there a way to do the same thing without copying the set in an array?